# How to ".call" a function of another contract which uses ".call"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, reentrancy, evm

So, I'm learning advanced smart contract development. Two days ago, I learned about Reentrancy attacks and then I also created two contracts `Protocol.sol` (vulnerable contract) + `Hacker.sol` (attacker contract) to put my knowledge to the test. I was able to perform everything smoothly, I was importing the Protocol.sol (ABI + address) contract in my `Hacker.sol`. Today, I learned that we can call another smart contract function without importing the ABI, just using the contract address via ".call" & delegate call.
So, again to put my knowledge to the test, I used Protocol.sol & Hacker.sol.

`Protocol.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Protocol {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable {
        require(balances[msg.sender] > 0, "BRUH");
        (bool success, ) = (msg.sender).call{value: 1 ether}("");
        require(success);
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

`Hacker.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Hacker {

    function protocolDeposit(address protocol) public payable {
        (bool success,) = protocol.call{value: msg.value}(abi.encodeWithSignature("deposit()"));
        require(success, "call failed");
    }

    function attack(address protocol) public payable {
        (bool hacked,) = protocol.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw()"));
        require(hacked, "attack failed");
    }

    // fallback() external payable {
    //     (bool hacked,) = protocol.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw()"));
    //     require(hacked, "hack failed");
    // }

    function rektMoney() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

The problem, I am facing right now is calling `withdraw()` func. I am able to deposit ETH using `Hacker.sol` into `Protocol.sol` but I'm unable to call `withdraw()` using `attack`

Maybe it is because the `withdraw` func in the `protocol.sol` is also using `call` to transfer ETH.

**How to ".call" a function of another contract which is using ".call" as well?**

How I can solve this problem? Pls Help, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to implement `receive` or `fallback` function in order to receive money in the hacker contract.

```
    fallback() external payable {}
```

Working now Alhumdulilah